# How to override xml file of a portlet in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to make an ext plugin and want to override the `liferay-portlet.xml` file of Journal Article Portlet. I am new to the ext plugins and don't know what to do. I tried with `liferay-portlet-ext.xml` file inside `ext-web/docroot/WEB-INF` folder but compilation error occurs. So I want to ask how to override liferay-portlet.xml of some portlet? Please help...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What source are you adding to it and what compilation error are you facing?

Comment: the error is - `The content of element type "liferay-portlet-app" must match "(portlet*,role-mapper*,custom-user-attribute*)".` The source I am adding is `<portlet-data-handler-class>com.liferay.portlet.journal.lar.CustomJournalPortletDataHandlerImpl.java</portlet-data-handler-class>`

Comment: It means you must be using such a tag, which is not support by your DTD.

Comment: What version of Liferay are you using? Also, share the contents of `liferay-portlet-ext.xml` by editing your question.

Comment: The xml file must be indicating an error in IDE editor regarding non compliance to DTD.Please check either on the whether tag is valid or not and it's sequencing with respect to other elements too.